# Wait another call to complete on async calls in Angular 4

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, oauth-2.0

we're using and implementing OAuth2 on our Angular 4 (currently on 4.4.6) application and we have the following scenario:

- There are some async calls on the application (let's call it s1 and
  s2).
- They both use a token to make requests
- If the token is expired, it will call another service and refresh it.
- Once it's refreshed, the request needs to be remade.

The problem is that since the calls are async, this refresh service is being called 2 or more times at same time, genereating various tokens. The application works, but this is not the correct behaviour.

I got something like this for each call:

```
odata(url) {
 return this.http.get(this.URL, {
     headers: headers
 }).map(res => res.json()).catch(error => {
     if (error.status === 401) {
         return this.refreshToken().flatMap(resRefresh => {
             localStorage.setItem('access_token', resRefresh.access_token);
             return this.odata(url);
         })
     } else {
         return Observable.throw(error);
     }
 });}
```

And the refresh token service is just another call with an url.

This is working, but as I said, there are 2 or more refresh calls at the same time. My question is if there is some way to block the second request while I wait for the refresh response, and then remake the call (like, call then both -> both will 401 -> so call refresh -> refresh is already called -> so wait -> refresh was ok -> remake both calls).

Thanks

Comment: you can do a filter of undefined after the resetToken action to avoid the second call